# Difference between $.ajax() and Backbone's .fetch() or .save() functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm trying to set data on my user model via the "signIn" function in my view:

```
initialize: function() {
    console.log('Sign in view initialized');
    this.render();

    this.userModel = new UserModel();
    this.collection = new UserCollection();
},

signIn: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/app/api/User.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $.param({
            req: "REQUSERSIGNIN",
            platform: "WEB",
            useremail: $('#userSignIn #userEmail').val(),
            userpass: $('#userSignIn #userPassword').val()
        }),
        success: function(response) {

            self.userModel.set({
                handle: response.HANDLE,
                email: response.EMAIL,
                uuid: response.UUIDUSER,
                userpic: response.USERPIC,
                tokenlogin: response.TOKENLOGIN
            });

            console.log(self.userModel.get("tokenlogin"));
        }
    });
},
```

I've read that the .fetch() or .save() is the backbone way of doing things, but I can't seem to set my UserModel when I use fetch. When I do it the jQuery.ajax() way though, it acts as desired.

Can someone explain to me the difference between doing it in $.ajax() or doing it via .fetch etc.

edit:

Here is my model code

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        handle: '',
        email: '',
        uuid: '',
        userpic: '',
        tokenlogin: ''
    },
});
```

Comment: Backbone.fetch and Backbone.save all eventually call jQuery.ajax. There must be something wrong with the configuration on your Model. Can you show your model code?

Comment: I added the model code above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by overriding your model's `fetch` method:

```
UserModel = Backbone.model.extend({
  defaults: {
    // ....
  },

  // set url for model (assumes app root is http://localhost/app)
  url: '/api/User.php',

  // pass custom parameters on fetch
  fetch: function (options) {
    var options = _.clone(options);

    // set our custom parameters
    options.req = "REQUSERSIGNIN";
    options.platform = "WEB";
    options.useremail = $('#userSignIn #userEmail').val();
    options.userpass = $('#userSignIn #userPassword').val();

    // call the Backbone method, which in turn calls $.ajax
    Backbone.sync.apply(this, options);
  },
});
```

Your model's Parse method should handle the response from the server just fine, since it seems like there is a one to one (response.handle will match model.attributes.handle). Without seeing the actual response it is a bit hard to know.